# KVO for scroll start & end in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Is there a way to use KVO (key value observing) to detect **scrollViewWillBeginDragging** and **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** in swift?

Edit: I tried

```
scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "dragging", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

But it's never called. If I observe for instance "contentOffset" in the same way, it's called. Is it KVC compliant?

Comment: You could try observing the `dragging` property

Comment: Good suggestion, but my observer is never called (see edit in my original question)? @dan

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it is sufficient for your question, but while you may not be able to observe isDragging or isDecelerating directly you can track them as your observing contentOffset. To find the start and end of dragging you can simply track when isDragging changes from false to true and vice versa by creating a global Boolean (here draggingInitiated) and including something like this in your observeValue:

```
if !draggingInitiated && scrollView.isDragging {
    draggingInitiated = true
    print("Started Dragging")
} else if draggingInitiated && !scrollView.isDragging {
    draggingInitiated = false
    print("Ended Dragging")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on @Philip De Vries

**Swift 5**

1. add observer

   ```
   scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset", options: .new, context: nil)
   ```
2. observe

   ```
   // MARK: - Observation

   override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
       if let obj = object as? UIScrollView {
         if obj == self.scrollView && keyPath == "contentOffset" {

           scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)

           if !draggingInitiated && scrollView.isDragging {
             draggingInitiated = true
             onStartDraggin()
           } else if draggingInitiated && !scrollView.isDragging {
             draggingInitiated = false
             onReleaseDragging()
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ```
3. cleanUp

   ```
   private func removeObsrvers() {
      scrollView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentOffset")
   }
   ```

Answer (score -3):

You can add observers using NSNotification center.

In the viewDidLoad of your VC,

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.informBeginDragging), name: "begin", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.informEndDragging), name: "end", object: nil)

}
```

You can do anything in the following two methods

```
    func informBeginDragging() {
    //do something
}

func informEndDragging() {
    //do something
}
```

And these two methods will be triggered when scroll view begin dragging or end dragging

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("end", object: nil)
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("begin", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have another class that needs to be the delegate of the same scrollView outside of my module, so I cannot use those delegate methods. Thank you though

Comment: It does't matter if you use them in other classes, it will only post the notification with your wanted name. I cannot see why this is not working. Or I may not get your question

Comment: The delegate for my scrollView is inside another module. I cannot put any code in there.